# Error when importing Excel file to grid view

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, import

I am using below code to import Excel file data into a Grid view. But I am getting an error.

```
 protected void uploadLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = "Items";
            string path = Server.MapPath(StyleOperationsFileUpload.FileName);
            string Constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2;'";
            OleDbConnection OleCon = new OleDbConnection(Constr);
            OleDbCommand OleCom = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", OleCon);
            OleCon.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter OleAdapObj = new OleDbDataAdapter(OleCom);
            DataTable DatTabObj = new DataTable();
            OleAdap.Fill(DatTab);
            UploadGridView.DataSource = DatTab;
            UploadGridView.DataBind();
        }
```

The error is as below

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object
>   'Items$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and
>   the path name correctly. If 'Items$' is not a local object, check your
>   network connection or contact the server administrator.

Full stack trace and error as below

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=-2147217865
  HResult=-2147217865
  Message=The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Items$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Items$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.
  Source=Microsoft Access Database Engine
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
       at StyleOperations.Operations.uploadLinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Developments\On Going Developments\StyleOperations\StyleOperations\StyleOperations\Operations.aspx.cs:line 145
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Below is the Format of the excel file. Name of the excel file is **Sheet1**

```
| 1 |DESCRIPTION|  SMV   |SEQ NO
| 2 |   Des1    |  1.2   | 1
| 3 |   Des2    |  2.5   | 2
| 4 |   Des3    |  5.8   | 3
| 5 |   Des4    |  4.2   | 4
```

Comment: Something is missing? What does the excel look like?

Comment: @JanAndersen I have edited the question and added the Format of the Excel file. Please have a look at it.

Comment: did you rename default `sheet1` to `Items` or created new sheet for `Item` ?

Comment: ^ because, otherwise you need to change the value you've assigned to name to: string name = "Sheet1";

Comment: No, I am modifying the name **Sheet1** to **Items** in my code. Even I was not modifying the name, I was getting the same error. Just the name **Item** has replaced to **Sheet1** in error :D

Comment: try to enter `Sheet1` instead of `Items` in your select command

Comment: @ershoaib I Tried that also. But Did not work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: So what is the name of the Sheet in the excel file?

Comment: make sure that you have sheet that name has `Items` and in your select command this also point to `Items`

Comment: @JanAndersen Name of the excel file is Sheet1 (default name). I am renaming the sheet name as Items in my code. But I used the same default name previously, but it did not work. That is why I renamed the Sheet name. But Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Check my answer.. and check the results. Perhaps we've gotten a bit off course. The Filepath is your Source, and the name of the Sheet in the Excel is your Table (Items).

Comment: What's up? Did you work it out?

Answer (score 1):

Just making sure, we're on the same page here, erm, more or less.

I fixed a few errors, that would have stopped you anyway..

[image: The filename and Sheet]

```
// The name of the EXCEL-SHEET in the Excel File.
string name = "Items$";
// The Pathname of the Excel File
string path = Server.MapPath(StyleOperationsFileUpload.FileName);
// Getting the Extension to check whether it's old or new Office file.
string Extension = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower();
// Default ConStr for "new" Excel (> 2003)
string ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2'";
if (Extension.Trim() == ".xls")
{
    // ConStr for old Excel 97-2003 Project
    ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2'";
}
OleDbConnection OleCon = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
if (OleCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    OleCon.Open();
}
// It seems that there might be some confusion about what that Sheet is called, so I would suggest checking up on what's in there.. 
bool doThatThing = false;
DataTable xTables = OleCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
foreach (DataRow xTable in xTables.Rows)
{
    // SheetsInFile:
    //sheetsInFile.Text += xTable["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    if (name == xTable["TABLE_NAME"].ToString())
        doThatThing = true;
}
if (doThatThing)
{
    OleDbCommand OleCom = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "]", OleCon);
    OleDbDataAdapter OleAdapObj = new OleDbDataAdapter(OleCom);
    DataTable DatTabObj = new DataTable();
    OleAdapObj.Fill(DatTabObj);
    UploadGridView.DataSource = DatTabObj;
    UploadGridView.DataBind();
}
// Don't forget to close Connection
OleCon.Close();
```

Perhaps add this to your front and include the sheetsInFile in the code-behind.

```
<asp:Label ID="sheetsInFile" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

--- Edit ---

Now, that you've got the Folderpath sorted, it might work with that.

```
string ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Folderpath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2'";
if (Extension.Trim() == ".xls")
{
    // ConStr for Excel 97-2003 Project
    ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Folderpath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2'";
}
OleDbConnection OleCon = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
if (OleCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    OleCon.Open();
}
// If you know there is only going to be one Sheet
// - with a variable name, that you can't rememeber...
name = OleCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
OleDbCommand OleCom = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "]", OleCon);
OleDbDataAdapter OleAdapObj = new OleDbDataAdapter(OleCom);
DataTable DatTabObj = new DataTable();
OleAdapObj.Fill(DatTabObj);
UploadGridView.DataSource = DatTabObj;
UploadGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hi @JanAnderson, Sorry for the delay. I tried it. The code executes until `foreach` without any error. In `foreach` first, it goes to `xTables.rows` and then to `in` and then it jumps directly to `if (doThatThing)`. Since the `bool` is set to `false`, the clause does not get checked and the excel file does not read.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to remove the double-slash on sheetsInFile and add that label to your output page so you can learn the "real" name of "Items" ;)

Comment: I tried that earlier also. But, `foreach` does not get triggered and therefore cannot get the real file name. The loop does not execute.

Comment: The foreach is not going through filenames, but Sheet names in the Excel file, as shown in the picture. Are you sure that you are working on right the file? I think you should check what your StyleOperationsFileUpload.FileName actually returns.

Comment: `StyleOperationsFileUpload.FileName` return path is `"D:\\Developments\\On Going Developments\\StyleOperations\\StyleOperations\\StyleOperations\\Operation_Update.xlsx"`. whic is the correct file path name. But the `foreach` does not loop through the sheets in the `Operation_Update.xlsx` file.

Comment: Can you share this file?

Comment: I found a way. Please check my below answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good for you :)) But, perhaps the original might work the new Folderpath? (see my edit)

Comment: Yeah, could be. I also thought the same after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I found an answer to that. @JanAndersen Thank you for your help. Below is my code. It is working fine now. :)

```
  using ClosedXML.Excel;
 protected void uploadLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(StyleOperationsFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
            string FolderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/" + FileName);
            StyleOperationsFileUpload.SaveAs(FolderPath);

            using (XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(FolderPath))
            {
                IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);
                DataTable DatTab = new DataTable();
                bool FirstRow = true;
                foreach (IXLRow row in worksheet.Rows())
                {
                    if (FirstRow)
                    {
                        foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                        {
                            DatTab.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                        }
                        FirstRow = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        DatTab.Rows.Add();

                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                        {
                            DatTab.Rows[DatTab.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                            i++;
                        }

                    }

                }

                UploadGridView.DataSource = DatTab;
                UploadGridView.DataBind();
            }
            SaveLinkButton.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please Restart the system: " + ex + "')</script>");
        }

    }
```